# Control DataTable to CSV toString() formatting

Tags: c#, linq

Following a [question I asked and the advice on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142894/how-to-control-datatable-to-csv-tostring-formatting) I implemented the following solution. Are there any downsides to such a solution? Is there a better way to make it changeable when I need to control formatting of other types like `double` and `float` where I have more than one occurrence of each in the `dataLine[]`?

```
    public void Save(DataTable newMyDataTable)
    {
        String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        try
        {
            lock (writtingLock)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataTable = newMyDataTable;
                fileId = dataTable.TableName;
                PathMaker path = new PathMaker(fileId);
                path.Make();
                // writing the table to a file
                using (StreamWriter swr =
                    new StreamWriter(File.Open(path.filePath, FileMode.Create), Encoding.Default, 1000000))
                // change buffer size and Encoding to your needs
                {
                    if (addHeader)
                    {
                        foreach (var dc in dataTable.Columns)
                        {
                            swr.Write(dc.ToString() + ",");
                        }
                        swr.WriteLine();
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        Object[] dataLine = dr.ItemArray;
                        // extract date time and format it
                        var dateTime = dataLine.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)).Select(t => (DateTime)t).Select(x => x.ToString(dateTimeFormat)).ToArray();
                        // collect data other than date time
                        var otherData = dataLine.Where(o => o.GetType() != typeof(DateTime)).ToArray();
                        // build your string
                        string dateTimeToWrite = string.Join(",", dateTime);
                        string otherDataToWrite = string.Join(",", otherData.Select(x => x.ToString().TrimEnd(null)).ToArray());
                        string lineToWrite = dateTimeToWrite + "," + otherDataToWrite;
                        swr.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of `dataTable = newMyDataTable;`? Why not simply work with `newMyDataTable` directly? Note that `newMyDataTable` is a bad variable name anyway.

---

Ditto `fileId`: this is only used to pass to `PathMaker`, so why then not simply use `newMyDataTable.TableName`?

---

Ditto `dataLine`: why not work with `dr.ItemArray` directly?

---

`writtingLock` has a spelling error.

---

What is `dc`? Ditto `dr`? Use descriptive names; using abbreviations isn't making your code faster.

---

Why assign `dateTime` and `otherData` when you could easily make this one line? Even better: why not move this code -- including the `string.Join` -- to separate methods?

Example:

```
string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray
     .Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
     .Select(x => ((DateTime)x).ToString(dateTimeFormat)));
```

---

Why assign `lineToWrite` when you could simply write `swr.WriteLine(dateTimeToWrite + "," + otherDataToWrite);`?

---

`filePath` is a property, so it should be PascalCase.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestions, i will follow them, But i am not sure how to one line the `dateTime` and `otherData` ?  can you show me how ? i am very new to LINQ and C# (4 months)

Comment: Another question about the property having a PascalCase, where can i find all the naming conventions ? googling reveal sooo many opinions, what do you use ?

Comment: @BinaryA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your time format should be a constant. After all, it isn't dependant on any other code in your method.

```
private const string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

There's wayyy too much things in that `lock`. Locks need to be used cautiously, you don't want to bottleneck your application with a `lock`. Try to remove *everything* that's not related to the thread-safe operation from the `lock`.

And well, looking at your code, *nothing* needs thread safety here. *Maybe* your "write" operation needs to be thread-safe so you don't write in the same file with two different threads, but that's all. And even there, in such a case I don't think a `lock` is the good solution.

You should use the `is` operator instead of comparing types like you're doing actually :

```
o.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)
```

becomes

o is DateTime

Better eh?

Finally, most of the comments are kind of useless. Stuff like `// build your string` can be deduced by looking at your code! :)